# List inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, list, templates, inheritance

I'm doing a program that involve a lot of lists of multiple class. I'm pretty sure it has a name but I don't really know how to call it, what I would like to do is to make a common list which contain some functions (like element insertion, getter...) which all lists inherit and can use functions of the common list. So my question is how to do it with an example if possible.
I've made a header code example below.

```
class CommonList {
  public:
        // Add some functions
        // T here is not a class I've made.
        void insere(T element);
        T getElement(int id);
  protected:
        std::map<int,T> m_map;
};

class A {
    public: A();
}

class B {
    public: B();
}

class ListA : public CommonList {
    // Tell the program that element T are ONLY object of class A.
    // Like if I would have made this.
    /*
  public:
        void insere(A element);
        A getElement(int id);
  protected:
        std::map<int,A> m_map;
    */
};

class ListB : public CommonList {
    // Same for B.
}
```

Comment: You can use a template for `CommonList`

Comment: It is called [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) (but there's no inheritance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure it has a name but I don't really know how to call it

The word you are looking for is a **template** class.

And this is how it is being done:

```
template <typename T>
class CommonList {
public:
    void insert(T element){
        /* Implement your insert function here */
    };
    T getElement(int id){
        /* Implement your getElement function here */
    };
protected:
    std::map<int,T> m_map;
};
```

And then you can simply create any type of that list, for example:

```
int main(){
    CommonList<int> int_list;
    my_list.insert(7);
    CommonList<double> double_list;
    my_list.insert(4.3);
}
```

You may of course also inherit from this class to and override the functions as you wish.

```
class A{}; 
class ListA : public CommonList<A>{
    // ... 
};
```

Or as a template

```
template <typename T>
class ListT : public CommonList<T>{
    // ...
};
```

Comment: I think template class is indeed key to resolve my problem. But I want to implement specific functions for a CommonList<A> and CommonList<B> for example.

Comment: Look up template specialization http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization . You can do `class ListA : public CommonList<A> { method_for_a(...){...} };`

Comment: Thank you. But is there something else to add ? Cause I get a "undefined reference to CommonList<A>::CommonList()" during compilation at List<A> constructor implementation.

Comment: I think you still need to understand more about the entire concept of using Templates. Please read more about it. See the link to the documentation at the bottom of my answer and also the link csiz gave in the comment. There are many examples for this over the net.